# I cannot move the playhead in the Timeline with the mouse

Tags: animation

sometimes it happens that I cannot grab the playhead and move it forward or back along the timeline.
Indeed, if I use the left click of the mouse, it will automatically zoom in into the timeline, and this is really tedious (I can move the playhead only with the keyboard arrows).
But the Blender manual says "The Playhead can be set or moved to a new position by pressing or holding LMB in scrubbing area at the top of the timeline."

Sometimes the LMB works, sometimes not.
Have anyone else had the same issue?

Comment: Never happened to me. Does it always work on startup? If so, can you try to isolate the steps that make it stop working?

Comment: the software remembers the "new button" (I mean the left click of the mouse for zooming into the timeline) even if I close and reopen Blender. So when this happen I have to go to File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings. And this is at the moment the only solution to bring the timeline to its normal functionality, where I can grab the playhead with my LMB

Comment: Honestly I don't remember what are the steps that bring me to this issue. It happens without any apparent reason. However I am referring to the timeline in Grease Pencil. Maybe I touch a few buttons that I shouldn't...